# Android - How to get header into response using asynctask android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have used this code. Now, I want to get the header into the response. How can I do this?

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url_.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
String jsonStr = convertStreamToString( in );

public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream input) throws Exception {
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  String line = null;

  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
  }

  input.close();
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: can you try HttpResponse.getHeaders() method?

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-http-response-header-in-java/ refer this link

Comment: for this i have to change method everywhere in code , there is no option to get using current code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get answer :

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet("https://api***********.php");
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
Header[] headers = httpResponse.getAllHeaders();
String Token="";

for (Header header : headers) {

  System.out.println("Key : " + header.getName()+ " ,Value : " + header.getValue());

    if (header.getName().equals("your_parm_key")) {

       Token = header.getValue();

       }
}
```

Comment: Your question mentions that you need to use async task, but your answer does not done that. Also it looks like you are making Network call on main thread, which is not allowed.

Comment: Thanks @AlokGupta ,no problem , but for me everything is working fine , and i get header also ,

Comment: also you can see as i post the question , its also code of inside doinbackground of asynctask , you can read question again , thanks @AlokGupta